# Дневная и ночная тема

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

Я создал отельный класс SharePref

```
public class SharedPref {
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "mysettings";
    public static final String NIGHT_MODE = "NightMode";
    public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER = "counter";
    SharedPreferences mySharedPref ;
    public SharedPref(Context context) {
        mySharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    // this method will save the nightMode State : True or False
    public void setNightModeState(Boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(NIGHT_MODE,value);
        editor.apply();
    }
    // this method will load the Night Mode State
    public Boolean loadNightModeState (){
        return mySharedPref.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE,false);
    }
}
```

После я создал активити Settings_app в котором расположен код который должен менять тему на день и ночь. но при изменений темы тема меняется но при перезапуска приложений тема не сохраняется.

```
public class Settings_App extends AppCompatActivity {
    CheckBox day_night_switch;
    public static SharedPref sharedPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        day_night_switch = findViewById(R.id.switch_day_night);
        if (sharedPref.loadNightModeState()) {
            day_night_switch.setChecked(true);
        }
        day_night_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    sharedPref.setNightModeState(true);
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    day_night_switch.setChecked(true);

                } else {
                    sharedPref.setNightModeState(false);
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    day_night_switch.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Не видно что бы вы вашу тему назначали где-то помимо активити настроек. Тему надо во всех активити назначать из префов до super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Если Вам не сложно можете показать один пример пожалуйста

Comment: С телефона сложно. И не хватает информации чтобы вам понятный пример показать. Просто до вызова super. во всех активити назначьте тему из префов и все. Это в одну строку можно сделать

Comment: MUltilanguage тоже так же надо сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Супер я сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос))) спасибо за совет тоже помог очень))
Просто надо было написать этот код в других активи:

```
sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
if(sharedPref.loadNightModeState()==true){
    sharedPref.setNightModeState(true);
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
} else {
    sharedPref.setNightModeState(false);
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
}
```